# For what $a\neq0$ does $a_{n+1}=1/a_{n}+a_{n}/2$ the sequence converge

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

The problem is stated as:

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $a_1 = a \neq 0$, for what $a\neq0$ does $a_{n+1}=1/a_{n}+a_{n}/2$ is the sequence converging?

**My attempt**

I'm thinking about using the fix - point theorem. So, we have to show 2 things:

- $f: I \mapsto I$ for some closed interval $I = [a,b]$
- That there $\exists C < 1 : |f(x)-f(y)| < C|x-y|$

Let $f(x) := 1/x + x/2$, differentiating we get:

$f'(x) = -1/x^2 + 1/2 = \frac{x^2-2}{2x^2}$ which is monotonically decreasing on the interval $(-\sqrt2,0) \cup(0, \sqrt2)$ and monotincally increasing on the interval $(-\infty,-\sqrt2)\cup (\sqrt2, \infty)$. They might be potentially good intervals to choose later.

To show that there $\exists C < 1 : |f(x)-f(y)| < C|x-y|$, we apply the mean value theorem, and find that our $C = 1/2$ from our derivative, which of course is strictly less than 1.

Before we choose our interal I, let's try and solve for $f(x) = x$. We get:

$x = 1/x + x/2$ which gives us the solutions $x=\pm \sqrt2$. Of course, the fix point is unique, and has to be within our chosen interval I. Furthermore, the fix - point theorem states that the convergence is independent on the starting point $a_1$ for our interval I. However, I don't really know how to move on from this. I'm thinking that we can choose that $a \in [-\sqrt2,0) \cup(0, \sqrt2]$ as our only possibility, since that's the closest to a closed interval.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the letter $a$ for two distinct things?

Comment: Why are you rejecting $|a|>\sqrt 2$?

Comment: $f'(x)$ is increasing for all positive $x$ and  decreasing for all negative $x$

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to consider the problem for $a>0$ as if we have two sequences with $a_{0} = a$ and $b_{0} = -a$ with the same above recurrence relation then $a_{n} = - b_{n}$.

From

$$(x-\sqrt{2})^2 \geq 0$$

we have

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{2} \geq \sqrt{2}\text{ for }x \geq 0$$

Thus $a_{1},a_{2},...$ are all atleast $\sqrt{2}$. Furthermore

$$ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{x}{2} \leq x \text{ for }x \geq \sqrt{2}$$

Hence we have

$$a_{1} \geq a_{2} \geq ...\geq \sqrt{2}$$

Thus $a_{1},a_{2},...$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence which conveges to some value $c$ atleast $\sqrt{2}$ by the monotone convergence theorem. Now $c$ must satisfy the equation $c = \frac{1}{c}+\frac{c}{2}$; thus $c \in \{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$, but $c \geq \sqrt{2}$ thus $c = \sqrt{2}$.

Hence we have the following;

If $a > 0$ the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$

If $a < 0$ the sequence converges to $-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure how you went from the first step to the second in your solution. I'd be glad if you could clarify that for me.

Comment: I used monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Why such a complicated argument in your edit. You already proved that the limit exists and is at least $\sqrt 2$, now just take limits in the recurrence relation. Is more direct and the standard way to find such limits in recurrence relations (or even candidates for limits, when it's done before proving the existence of the limit)

Comment: Fair point.....